# How to erase rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, rails-migrations

I ran heroku run rake db:migrate and noticed several errors. One very obvious error is that there are migration entries that I never created, for instance:

```
Migrating to CreateActiveCampaignMetros (20131211034603)
==  CreateActiveCampaignMetros: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:active_campaign_metros)
   -> 0.0019s
==  CreateActiveCampaignMetros: migrated (0.0020s) ============================

Migrating to CreateActiveCampaignDows (20131211034850)
==  CreateActiveCampaignDows: migrating =======================================
-- create_table(:active_campaign_dows)
   -> 0.0018s
==  CreateActiveCampaignDows: migrated (0.0019s) ==============================
```

These are two migrations that appear in the command window that I never created as there are no migration files for them, and thusly are preventing my app from working in production.

How can I remove these migrations entirely from my app?

Answer (score 0):

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20131211034603
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20131211034850

rails destroy migration CreateActiveCampaignMetros
rails destroy migration CreateActiveCampaignDows
```

or

```
rails destroy migration create_active_campaign_metros
rails destroy migration create_active_campaign_dows
```

Comment: This noted that it removed the migration, but then running rake db:migrate still migrated the, as it should be, removed file...